# Require arbitrary files as if they were in the /public directory with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails project where I want to be able to store a number of arbitrary files (HTML, CSS, PNG, etc.) in a **separate directory**, but be able to access them as if they were being stored in /public. I want to be able to access use these files when I load a page; for example, create

`{folder outside of rails project}/assets/stylesheets/base.css`

and require it with `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "base" %>` in my layout.

Short of creating a symlink from the folder to /public, is there any other way to programatically configure Rails to treat said folder like /public?

Answer (score 0):

In application.rb you can tell rails from where to take assets file

config.assets.prefix = "/public" // this is path

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your config/application.rb file.

Its allow public folder also.

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "public")
```

Comment: I tried `config.assets/paths << Pathname.new('/absolute/path/to/folder')` and it did not work.